# Creating two pipes with three execlp small error somewhere C System Programming

Tags: c, pipe, parent-child

I'm trying to create three child processes and two pipes that will execute three `execlp()`.  When my program runs, however, the output is not what I expect.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    pid_t  pid = getpid();
    printf("STARTING PROCESSXXX %d\n",pid);

    int c1Toc2[2];
    int c2Toc3[2];

    if(pipe(c1Toc2) == -1)
    {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if(pipe(c2Toc3) == -1)
    {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int rValue = fork();

    if(rValue == -1)
    {
        perror("Child_1");
    }
    else if (rValue == 0)
    {
        printf("CHILD 1:  ");
        printf("PROCESS ID IS: %ld \tMY PARENT ID IS: %ld\trValue IS: %d\n", (long) getpid(), (long) getppid(), rValue);

        dup2(c1Toc2[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(c1Toc2[0]);
        close(c2Toc3[0]);

        execlp("ps", "ps", "-ef", NULL);

        exit(0);
    }

    rValue = fork();

    if(rValue == -1)
    {
        perror("Child_2");
    }
    else if (rValue == 0)
    { 
        printf("CHILD 2:  ");
        printf("PROCESS ID IS: %ld \tMY PARENT ID IS: %ld\trValue IS: %d\n",
                (long) getpid(), (long) getppid(), rValue);

        dup2(c1Toc2[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(c1Toc2[1]);

        dup2(c2Toc3[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(c2Toc3[0]);
        printf("CHILD 2 : goodbye\n");
        execlp("grep","grep","root",NULL);

        printf("CHILD 2 : goodbye\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    rValue = fork();

    if(rValue == -1)
    {
        perror("Child_3");
    }
    else if (rValue == 0)
    { 
        printf("CHILD 3:  ");
        printf("PROCESS ID IS: %ld \tMY PARENT ID IS: %ld\trValue IS: %d\n",
                (long) getpid(), (long) getppid(), rValue);

        dup2(c2Toc3[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(c2Toc3[1]);
        close(c2Toc3[0]);
        printf("CHILD 3 : \n");
        execlp("sort","sort","-n", "-k4",NULL);

        printf("CHILD 3 : goodbye\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    close(c1Toc2[1]);
    close(c1Toc2[0]);

    close(c2Toc3[1]);
    close(c2Toc3[0]);
    // Add the code for the two children  here
    sleep(3);
    printf("PARENT: PROCESS Waiting on children to complete\n");

    printf("Final Print Statement before exit\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Asking SO for debugging is fine but it shall be not done all the time.. Said that, verify you close and dup pipes correctly. And you are giving child the proper pipe end..

Comment: What is the output that you are getting versus what you want?  Nothing jumps out at me as being obviously wrong.

Comment: printf("CHILD  1/2/3  : goodbye\n"); will never reach in your code.. If it's that you expected

Comment: When I ran your code, I noticed that the grep child process hung.  This might be because you didn't close the write side of the pipe in the 'ps' child, so EOF was never posted to grep, so it sat there waiting for more input.

Comment: You won't see the "CHILD 2: goodbye" before the grep child calls execlp because you've already dup'ed its stdout to the write side of the pipe heading to the sort process.  Obviously, that status line will also improperly head to your sort program.

Comment: Yes the only problem with the code was that I had to close all four file descriptors in each child and the parent. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't close the pipe file descriptors in the children and so, because you dup'ed them over to STDOUT_FILENO (e.g. - grep child), even though the program was done its regular output it didn't fully exit and post an EOF to the next child process (i.e. - sort) and so those children hung around waiting forever.

I'm not entirely sure why your grep process refused to exit like normal because it does seem that the ps child exits, which should post an EOF to the grep child's stdin.

Here's a version that does what you want:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  pid_t pid = getpid();

  printf("PARENT: STARTING PROCESSXXX %d\n",pid);

  int c1Toc2[2];
  int c2Toc3[2];

  if (pipe(c1Toc2) == -1)
  {
    perror("pipe");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  if (pipe(c2Toc3) == -1)
  {
    perror("pipe");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  int rValue = fork();

  if (rValue == -1)
  {
    perror("Child_1");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  else if (rValue == 0)
  {
    printf("CHILD 1: PROCESS ID IS: %ld \tMY PARENT ID IS: %ld\trValue IS: %d\n", (long) getpid(), (long) getppid(), rValue);

    dup2(c1Toc2[1], STDOUT_FILENO);

    close(c1Toc2[0]);
    close(c1Toc2[1]);
    close(c2Toc3[0]);
    close(c2Toc3[1]);

    execlp("ps", "ps", "-ef", NULL);
    perror("CHILD 1: execlp");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  rValue = fork();

  if (rValue == -1)
  {
    perror("Child_2");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  else if (rValue == 0)
  { 
    printf("CHILD 2: PROCESS ID IS: %ld \tMY PARENT ID IS: %ld\trValue IS: %d\n", (long) getpid(), (long) getppid(), rValue);

    dup2(c1Toc2[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    dup2(c2Toc3[1], STDOUT_FILENO);

    close(c1Toc2[0]);
    close(c1Toc2[1]);
    close(c2Toc3[0]);
    close(c2Toc3[1]);

    execlp("grep","grep","root",NULL);
    perror("CHILD 2: execlp");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  rValue = fork();

  if (rValue == -1)
  {
    perror("Child_3");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  else if (rValue == 0)
  { 
    printf("CHILD 3: PROCESS ID IS: %ld \tMY PARENT ID IS: %ld\trValue IS: %d\n", (long) getpid(), (long) getppid(), rValue);

    dup2(c2Toc3[0], STDIN_FILENO);

    close(c1Toc2[0]);
    close(c1Toc2[1]);
    close(c2Toc3[0]);
    close(c2Toc3[1]);

    execlp("sort","sort","-n", "-k4",NULL);
    perror("CHILD 3: execlp");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  close(c1Toc2[0]);
  close(c1Toc2[1]);
  close(c2Toc3[0]);
  close(c2Toc3[1]);

  printf("PARENT: PROCESS Waiting on children to complete\n");
  sleep(3);
  printf("PARENT: Final Print Statement before exit\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks more or less right, but it does seem to reflect an imperfect understanding of fork / exec and child process management.

For one thing, note that the exec-family functions, including `execlp()`, do not return except on failure.  Your code seems to assume otherwise.  In particular, the child processes will not print "goodbye" messages after calling `execlp()` unless the `execlp()` call fails.  You *should* handle the (failure) case in which `execlp()` does return, but normally you would do so with error-handling / error-reporting code.

Also, each process, including the parent, should close those file descriptors it isn't going to use.  That includes closing a FD after duplicating it onto one of the standard file numbers, and closing all file descriptors intended exclusively for other processes.  You miss several of those:

- Child 1 fails to close file descriptors `c1Toc2[1]` (after duplicating it) and `c2Toc3[1]`.
- Child 2 fails to close file descriptors `c1Toc2[0]` and `c2Toc3[1]` (after duplicating them).

Furthermore, it is pointless for the parent process to `sleep()` to wait on its children.  If it wanted to ensure that they completed and/or to obtain their exit statuses, then it should use `wait()` or `waitpid()`.  If it were not going to exit immediately after, then it should definitely use one of those functions, else the child processes will hang around as zombie processes until the parent exits.  No amount of `sleep()` is sufficient to **ensure** that the child processes finish.  If you don't care about any of those things, on the other hand, then you can just let the parent exit.  There's no special advantage in that case to keeping it around.

I don't know whether any of those explains the unexpected behavior you see, because you haven't explained what that is.